# QSqlTableModel::setRecord inserts a new row instead of changing existing one

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

Here is how my code looks:

```cpp
bool
ProtocolRepository::update(const Protocol& protocol)
{
  auto record = model->record(protocol.id);
  if (record.isEmpty()) {
    return false;
  }
  record.setValue("name", protocol.name);

  record.setGenerated("name", false);
  record.setGenerated("id", false);

  if (!model->setRecord(protocol.id, record)) {
    return false;
  }
  return model->submitAll();
}
```

Instead of changing protocols name `setRecord` inserts same row with new id and default sql name.
Here is sql script of table creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS protocols
(
    id                INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name              TEXT      NOT NULL DEFAULT UNKNOWN,
    protocol_path              TEXT      NOT NULL DEFAULT UNKNOWN,
    created_date      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_date      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    is_pinned         NUMBER(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    execution_seconds INTEGER            DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Using qt5, clang and sqlite db

I tried to do same thing but without `setGenerated` method and then `setRecord` just return false.
p.s. Record with such id exists and is not empty

Comment: Because you read it from row 'protocol.id' but set it to row '0'.

Comment: `protocol.id` was also 0 in this case. But anyway that was typo, thanks